# Domain administrator role that can only see users of that domain

Tags: users, domain-access

Is it possible to define a "Domain Administrator" that would only be able to see the users (in the People interface) assigned to the same domain as itself? I've got a few Domain Access modules installed, but I still can't seem to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [Domain Admin](http://drupal.org/project/domain_admin) module?  Looks like there's a bit of stuff in there.  It's a shame that a few of the features listed are currently missing for Drupal 7 though.

> Domain Admin adds more granular permissions to the Domain Access module and several of its sub-modules.
>
> Currently the module allows the site admin to delegate the following tasks:
>
> - Access the domain overview page - delegated user will only be able to see the domains assigned to him/her (not there in D7 yet)
> - Editing of domain record, domain settings and domain theme
> - Administer primary and secondary menus (also navigation in D6)
> - Translate interface into the domain language (wont be ported to D7 - use i10n_client instead)
> - View, edit and delete all unpublished/own unpublished nodes on domain (needs to be tested in D7)
> - Administer book outline/ rearrange child pages of nodes on domain (requires book module)
> - View webform results on domain (requires webform module)

Comment: I've tried it, and it does not offer the functionality I'm hoping for.